# preg_match: Get the content of a div with spaces in the class name

Tags: regex, preg-match

I cant get the right code and I believe its because of the spaces in the class name:

```
<div class="post entry-content  mess ">
```

Please notice the double space before "mess" and the space at the end. I cant change those. I want to get the contents of only the first div with that class. this is my code:

```
preg_match('/<div class=\"post entry\-content  mess \">(.*?)<\/div>/s', $bitch, $match );
```

Where is the error?

Thank you.

Comment: You have 2 spaces between "content" and "mess" in your regular expression.

Comment: Still, the space after "mess" is missing in your regular expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get that match to work regardless how many spaces are between class names using the following regular expression:

```
/<div[^>]*class=\'\s*post\s+entry\-content\s+mensaje\s*\'[^>]*>(.*)<\/div>/smU
```

Comment: does it matter there is actually something between <div and class? this is the actual code <div itemprop="commentText" class='post entry-content  mensaje '>

Comment: still not working. $match[1] is what returns the content, right?

Comment: Could you provide a sample text you're trying to match? I've tested the regular expression here https://regex101.com/r/tH9sA3/1 and it works.

Comment: I've checked the page source, I can see that each of the entries starts with <div itemprop="commentText" class='post entry-content  mensaje '>, so you should replace mess with mensaje.

Comment: They also use single quotes instead of double quotes. I'll update the regular exp

Comment: I did that from the beginning on my actual code. I didnt show it here to avoid confusion because of a non-english word but still wont work.

Comment: I've also added "m" modifier to allow for multiline matches

Comment: I've pasted the content of the page and the new regular expression in the testing tool and it works now

Comment: Almost there but now it throws the content of all the divs with that class on the page. Can it return only the content from the very FIRST div on the page?

Comment: Add the "ungreedy" modifier "U", I've updated the regexp

Comment: fixed! Thank you. All it needed was that U at the end so returns only the first value?